# How do I center a DIV in the exact center of a page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, center

I need to center a DIV in the exact center of a page using jquery.  My CSS style for the DIV is as follows:

```
#page-content #center-box{
 position:absolute;
 width:400px;
 height:500px;
 background:#C0C0C0;
 border:1px solid #000;
 }
```

and my jQuery for centering is as follows:

```
windowheight = $(window).height();
windowwidth = $(window).width();
pagecenterW = windowwidth/2;
pagecenterH = windowheight/2;
$("div#page-content div#center-box")
    .css({top: pagecenterH-250 + 'px', left: pagecenterW-200 + 'px'});
```

This code does not invoke any action on my page when refreshed.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry about the code being garbled within the question text, I'm not sure how to separate the code.

Comment: select the entire code and press `Cmd+K` or `Ctrl+K`. or click the small icon with the numbers `123` at the top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ujalu/edit)

Make sure you don't have any styles on #page-content that are constraining center-box and try putting your jquery code in the document ready event.

```
/*CSS*/
#center-box{
 position:absolute;
 width:400px;
 height:500px;
 background:#C0C0C0;
 border:1px solid #000;
 }

/*js*/
$(document).ready(function(){
  var windowheight = $(window).height();
  var windowwidth = $(window).width();
  var pagecenterW = windowwidth/2;
  var pagecenterH = windowheight/2;
  $("div#center-box")
      .css({top: pagecenterH-250 + 'px', left: pagecenterW-200 + 'px'});
});

/*html*/
<body>
  <div id="center-box">

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Id start with removing the  `+ 'px'` or add round brackets around `pagecenterH-250` and `pagecenterW-200`.

What you are doing there is `int + int - string`.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute, the box position does not change on window resize (landscape to portrait for example). Use fixed instead. See [jQuery center element to viewport using center plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281112/jquery-center-element-to-viewport-using-center-plugin) for a basic example.