# Centering a div on a page using jQuery when the page is longer than the window

Tags: jquery, html, center

I need to take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599996/how-do-i-center-a-div-in-the-exact-center-of-a-page-using-jquery) one step further.

The div I have is centered vertically using the following code:

```
var boxheight = $('#notifications').height();
var windowheight = $(window).height();
var boxheight = $('#notifications').height();
var pagecenterH = ((windowheight-boxheight)/2);
$('#notifications').animate({'top': pagecenterH});
```

That works great if the page is only as tall as the window, but if the page is much longer and the user is halfway down the page when they click to open the `#notifications` code above, the div appears centered from the top of the screen, so they may miss the box altogether.

How can I get the code to recognize where on the page the user is so that the div will appear vertically centered no matter how far down they scroll?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:fixed` to place the element relative to the window instead of relative to the page. That way it will show up centered, and remain centered even if the user scrolls.

Comment: aha! that actually does exactly what I need and is very simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use `document` instead of `window`. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GftBg/1/

In your code, replace `$(window).height()` with `$(document).height()`.

If you want a `<div>` to always be centered in the screen regardless of where the user scrolls after the `<div>` is loaded in, you **should** use `$(window).height()` and set the `<div>`'s position to fixed. You can see this in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GftBg/2/

Comment: That will center the element on the page instead of the window, but it can still appear outside the window. Actually, it's even more likely that it does...

Comment: @Guffa, not sure what you mean by that. My second option would center the div directly inside the window using `position:fixed`.

Comment: You added that after I wrote the comment.

Comment: @Guffa Actually, I added it two minutes before you wrote that comment (edit: `2010-12-27 18:18:32Z`, your comment: `2010-12-27 18:20:01Z`), you just didn't refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, in this we are first centering the div in window to to bring it in user view we add scroll top and scroll left to it -

```
    $('#notifications').css("position","absolute");
    $('#notifications').css("top", ( $(window).height() - $('#notifications').height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    $('#notifications').css("left", ( $(window).width() - $('#notifications').width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
```