# jQuery center element to viewport using center plugin

Tags: jquery, center, viewport

I am currently using the jQuery center plugin to center my div element and so far it works to an extend where it does center it to the containing parent container.  What I want it to do is to center it to the current browser viewport center.  How can that be done?

My setup is a simple link when clicked, a div will pop up like a modal that I want centered into the current browser viewport center.

Comment: Can you link the Plugin you use. In other way see at http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/, perhaps it can be does what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No plug-in is needed. This does the trick:

```
$('#yourElement').css('display', 'inline-block').wrap('<table style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse"><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;padding:0"></td></tr></table>');
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/EnrLn/1/

---

Same thing, but without the TABLE element. I use DIV's with `display:table` and `display:table-cell` instead:

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/EnrLn/2/

Comment: this is interesting but does it have to be a table? Can this not be done with a div?

Comment: awesome, that's perfect! thanks for the help...oh one more thing if you don't mind, since this is a popup, is there a way for me to have the window darken and only the popup opaque?

Comment: @Rick You can use RGBA to set the background of the outer DIV, but that will not work in IE8 and below. Demo here:  [http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/EnrLn/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/EnrLn/3/) Another demo would be my [W3 Viewer](http://www.w3viewer.com) - click on the "About" link in the bottom left corner to see the effect. If you want a solution that works in IE8 also, you will have to use a Microsoft's proprietary filters...

Comment: If I have a long window with contents outside the viewport, and I try to center an element, why does the current view jump? This does position an element in the center, but the scrollbar jumps up and the scrollbar changes a bit for some reason.

Comment: @user961627 If you're using my solution, that's because the element is removed from the flow. (The element is inserted into a wrapper which is absolutely positioned, which means that the element is no longer in the flow.) I think what you need is the "scrollTo" plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
jQuery( "#element_id" ).css( 'top', parseInt( ( jQuery( window ).height() / 2 ) + jQuery( document ).scrollTop() - jQuery( "#element_id" ).height() ) );
jQuery( "#element_id" ).css( 'left', parseInt( ( jQuery( document ).width() / 2 ) + jQuery( document ).scrollLeft() - jQuery( "#element_id" ).width() ) );
```

Comment: this seems to work on the vertical center but horizontal center is off to the left...I even changed the code to use outerWidth but no help.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you may need to use `.outerWidth()` and `.outerHeight()` rather than `.width()` and `.height()`.